# C# how to edit listview items from new form?

Tags: c#, listview

So I have a `ListView` that is populated with information and edit button in `form1`.
Now when i select item in `ListView` and click edit, I want it to bring me to `form2` and display selected items data.

*For example*, I select name from `ListView` hit edit it brings me to `form2` where is `TextBox`, lets say `textbox1 = Name` and `textbox2 = Age` and in my `List<data>` have 2 items in it name and age.

What i need now is, when I select one of the `ListView` items and pres edit it opens `form2` and loads name in `textbox1` and age in `textbox2` how can I do that ?

I was trying `listview_SelectedIndexChanged` event like this :

```
Form2 edit = new Form2();
edit.textBox1.Text = People[this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name;
edit.textBox2.Text = People[this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Age;
```

Is there any way to reference this to button click edit? or is there another way?

and how do I save changes afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the value in the form of constructor .
In your main form where you have your listbox store the value of the listbox selected value in a  variable and then in your button edit event call the constructor of the 2nd form

```
Form2 child= new Form2(Name,Age);
Form2.show()
```

In the 2nd form create global variables for name and age

```
 private string _name = String.Empty;
 private int _age;
```

Then create a constructor for your 2nd form

```
 public void Form2(string name, int age)
 {

  InitializeComponent();
  this._name = name;
  this._age = age;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Properties to pass data to Form2 and Events to return the Saved Data:

**Form1**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 edit = new Form2();
    edit.SaveEvent += new Form2.SaveEventHandler(edit_SaveEvent);  //Add event handler
    edit.name = People[this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name;
    edit.age = People[this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Age;
    edit.ShowDialog(this);
}

void edit_SaveEvent(object sender, SaveEventArgs e)
{
    //Do Your work here with e.newAge and e.newName
    ((Form2)sender).Close(); //Close Form2
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public delegate void SaveEventHandler(object sender, SaveEventArgs e);
    public event SaveEventHandler SaveEvent;
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = name;
        textBox2.Text = age;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveEvent(this, new SaveEventArgs(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text));
    }

}

public class SaveEventArgs
{
    public SaveEventArgs(string name, string age) {newName = name; newAge = age; }
    public String newName {get; private set;} // readonly
    public String newAge {get; private set;}
}
```

Comment: Well it works but there is a problem, when i have added more than 1 item to listview and i select for example first item, texboxes ir edit for loads data from item that was added last. any way to fix this?

Comment: @user1396678 the ListViews multiselect property is probably true allowing you to select more than one item. You may want to look into turning that off or try changing `People[this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name;` to something like `People[this.listView1.SelectedItems[this.listView1.SelectedItems.Count -1].Index].Name;`

Comment: editing works when i save changes it changes the right item, but the thing is that in edit textboxes it shows last input data.  for example there is name johan, jane, tim, i click on johan and hit edit it will show tim's information, but when i press save button it correctly updates johan information.

Comment: @user1396678 put a breakpoint on the button click event and check what information you are sending to the second form. It should only be showing what you are sending it.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom constructor for this

In Form 1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string name = People[this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name;
    int age = People[this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Age;
     Form2 edit = new Form2(name,age);

    edit.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

In Form 2

```
public form2(string name,int age)
{

        textBox1.Text = name;
        textBox2.Text = age.ToString();
}
```

Use oop concepts..It is nice.